# Remove specific string from given URL

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a URL example `image1-resize.jpg`, and I want to delete `-resize` and save `image1.jpg` in new variable.

How can I do that?

This is what I tried to do:

```
str1 += "<li><a href='#pic" + counter + "'><img src='admin/temp/hotelimg/" + temp_url.ToString() + "'/></a></li>";
string stt =temp_url.replace("-resize","");
str2 += "<div id='pic" + counter + "'><img src='admin/temp/hotelimg/" + stt.ToString() + "' width='550' height='370'/></div>";
```

Comment: Please do some research, this is a simple task

Comment: you should use `temp_url.replace("-resize","");`

Comment: @TheMohanAhuja please post your comment as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do your job:

```
temp_url.replace("-resize","");
```

**Note:** You should always search before putting questions here, since sometimes its really easy and need just small research on it.